# El uso del "por ciento" con el artículo definido/indefinido o incluso sin artículo

Tags: gramática, artículos

Como una regla general, la frase "por ciento" debe usarse con el artículo definido.

Ejemplo: "*Ha acordado con más **del** 92 por ciento de los acreedores.*"

Pero muchas veces observaba el uso con el artículo indefinido o incluso sin cualquier artículo.

En este video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xwuj2b_bCiU en 1:01:

"*Noventa y seis por ciento de los 18 000 nuevos casos...*" [Pues, al principio de la oración no hay ningún artículo]

Y en el mismo video también al principio de una oración (en 1:10):

"*El caso similar en España. **El** ochenta y tres por ciento...*"

También tengo unos ejemplos aquí que encontré con el uso del artículo indefinido:

"*Solo **un** siete por ciento de la población del país vive en zonas rurales.*"

"*Papá y mamá gastaron en viajes **un** veintisiete por ciento más que el año pasado.*"

"*El monto de la equidad del sistema actual se encuentra entre **un** 15 y **un** 16 por ciento.*"

¿De qué depende todo eso?

Comment: Parte de la respuesta la encuentras buscando información relacionada con oraciones intransitivas:
https://10oraciones.com/oraciones-intransitivas/


La otra parte de la respuesta la ecuentras al buscar la definición de artículos definidos e indefinidos.
https://www.spanish.cl/Grammar/Notes/Articulos_Definidos_Indefinidos.htm
"Un" denota incertidumbre, mientras que "el" denota certeza.

Comment: Después de haber buscado información en estos enlaces todavía no entiedo por qué no se usa ningún artículo al principio de "Noventa y seis por ciento de los 18 000 nuevos casos...". Pero respecto a incertidumbre y certeza - entendí.

Comment: Estuve intentando encontrar una buena referencia que pueda sustentar mi afirmación pero está dificil.
El asunto aquí es que en la frase "El noventa y seis por ciento de los 18.000 ...". "El" es un artículo definido y "96% de los 18.000 nuevos casos" es sustantivo definido, por que el artículo puede omitirse.

Aquí puedes empezar a entenderlo pero la verdad se quedan cortos en la explicación. https://open.books4languages.com/spanish-a1-grammar/chapter/omision-del-articulo/

Comment: Por cierto, encontré ese enlace bueno https://www.espanolavanzado.com/gramatica-tips/1885-articulo-con-porcentajes: "en España se usa siempre un artículo delante de los porcentajes, mientras que en Latinoamérica a veces se omite; en algunos casos el artículo definido (el) y el indefinido (un) son perfectamente intercambiables, en otros casos se prefiere uno frente a otro."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundéu tiene un [artículo](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/un-25-y-el-25-significan-lo-mismo-665/) al respecto en el que indica que "el 25%" y "un 25%" son prácticamente intercambiables y significan lo mismo:

> Según la *Nueva gramática de la lengua española*, de las Academias de la Lengua, el empleo de los [artículos *el* o *un*](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=wuPtjdXjSbXDCzsE) es indistinto en la mayoría de los contextos, aunque el primero es el único posible cuando se presenta el [resultado de un cómputo](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=bugtHhpRxEYJwyIt), como en «El veinte por ciento de diez es dos» (y no «Un veinte por cierto de diez es dos»).

En cuanto a la omisión del artículo, Fundéu la considera [arcaizante y menos recomendable, pero no incorrecta](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/porcentaje-con-o-sin-articulo-407/).